# "Cannot find path because it does not exist" but number of folders to process is different to number of folders in filetext

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have this situation

[image]

I don't want to change manually **temp.csv** before to use script. If then it's the script that does this to me, then that's fine by me

I may need to add a trailing slash to my folder names because I'm joining them again. I try out writing my values back to the console and see if they are actually correct, plus I can remove some of my path checking since you're using `-Force` already:

```
$csvpath = 'C:\tomp\temp.csv'
$invalid = "[{0}]" -f [RegEx]::Escape(([IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -join ''))
$sourcePath = 'C:\tomp\'

Import-Csv C:\temp\temp.csv -Header Title,FileName,Link -Delimiter ';' | 
  Group-Object Title | 
  Foreach {

    # I prefer to add a trailing slash to folder names
    $TargetFolder = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath (($_.Name -replace $invalid)+'\')

    # We don't have to create the new folders, because -Force will create them for us
    Foreach ($fileName in $_.Group.FileName) {
      $ValidFileName = $filename -replace $invalid
      $targetFile = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath $fileName

      # Write your values to the console - Make sure the folder is what it should be
      Write-Output "Moving '$targetFile' to '$TargetFolder'"
      Move-Item $targetFile $TargetFolder -Force -WhatIf
    }
  }
```

So the output looks like:

```
Moving 'C:\tomp\(1959 10) Showcase Presents n  22' to 'C:\tomp\Lanterna Verde - Le Prime Storie\'
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\tomp\(1959 10) Showcase Presents n  22 Destination: C:\tomp\Lanterna Verde - Le Prime Storie\".
```

But script doesn't work for different reason. I get this output

[image]

Inside  `C:\tomp` path I already have 4 folders available and these are

```
(1959 10) Showcase Presents n  22
(1959 12) Showcase Presents n  23
(1959 14) Showcase
le prime avventure
```

On the same path I have **temp.csv** file with this text

```
Lanterna Verde - Le Prime Storie;(1959 10) Showcase Presents n  22;
Lanterna Verde - Le Prime Storie;(1959 12) Showcase Presents n  23;beta;
Lanterna Verde - Le Prime Storie;alfa;(1959 14) Showcase;gamma;
Batman DC;da definire;le prime avventure;
```

I want that script move in this way

```
Lanterna Verde - Le Prime Storie
   |
   +-- (1959 10) Showcase Presents n  22
   +-- (1959 12) Showcase Presents n  23
   +-- (1959 14) Showcase
    
Batman DC
   |
   +--- le prime avventure
```

**Problems:**

a) script don't create 2 new folders and don't move folders within
b) script process `beta`, `alfa`, `da definire` as folders to move. But this is wrong because in `C:\tomp` I have only 4 folders and not 7 folders !! **I don't want** that process `beta`, `alfa`, `da definire`

Comment: Remarkable.. This is exactly the same question as asked here before, now deleted and reposted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1657554/change-a-position-based-script-to-move-folders-only-if-the-folder-name-exists-in?noredirect=1#comment2537874_1657554). The same advice then. Make the fields in your input file consistent, so that each value in a column has the same meaning.  Now, the folder name exists in the second column sometimes, but also in the third, fourth, wherever.. I.e. remove the "spam" from it. How did you guys create that file anyhow? Must be a better way to do that I think.

Comment: You're explicitly telling it to move those folders when you iterate through the *FileName* column. `Foreach ($fileName in $_.Group.FileName) {.. `  this is reading:  `(1959 10) Showcase Presents n  22`,`(1959 12) Showcase Presents n  23`,`alfa`, `da definire`. Did you forget your splitting the files into 3 culumns and only reading from one?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala mm..yes, it should read only from one column and move only if that folder name in the single column (`; namefolder ;`) coincides with the folder present in `C: \ tomp` .  In what way can I say this? Because I don't want that process every Filename column but only ***some*** columns that meet my above condition

Comment: Then add an `if` condition.