# Fix script to allow a scanning of all fields for every row to find if that field contains a target folder name

Tags: powershell

This is an deepening extension to solve a [previously question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68046947/cannot-find-path-because-it-does-not-exist-but-number-of-folders-to-process-is)

> Since the input csv file is inconsistent, I cannot use that in this way.
> The folder to move to is not always in the same column, so any code trying to use that as input will hit the problem of the value not corresponding to the folder I want to move to. It simply reads garbage ("spam") where it expects the folder name.
> The only way to do it is by examining all fields for every row to find if that field contains a target folder name you can use. That means a LOT of Test-Path lines

This is the incriminated code part

```
Foreach ($fileName in $_.Group.FileName) {
       $ValidFileName = $filename -replace $invalid
       $targetFile = Join-Path -Path $TargetFolder -ChildPath $fileName
```

Error is explicitly telling it to move those folders when I iterate through the FileName column. `Foreach ($fileName in $_.Group.FileName) {..`  this is reading: `(1959 10) Showcase Presents n  22,(1959 12) Showcase Presents n  23,alfa, da definire.`

**My request**: Since that examination of all fields for every row is required so I ask for a code editing of this script. Also if this means a LOT of `Test-Path` lines I suppose that there is no alternative.
However this script below don't create folders and move anything so my request is to try to fix it

```
$csvpath = 'C:\temp\temp.csv'
$invalid = "[{0}]" -f [RegEx]::Escape(([IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -join ''))
$sourcePath = 'C:\temp\'

Import-Csv C:\temp\temp.csv -Header Title,FileName,Link -Delimiter ';' | 
  Group-Object Title | 
  Foreach {

    # I prefer to add a trailing slash to folder names
    $TargetFolder = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath (($_.Name -replace $invalid)+'\')

    # We don't have to create the new folders, because -Force will create them for us
    Foreach ($fileName in $_.Group.FileName) {
       $ValidFileName = $filename -replace $invalid
       $targetFile = Join-Path -Path $TargetFolder -ChildPath $fileName

      # Write your values to the console - Make sure the folder is what it should be
      Write-Output "Moving '$targetFile' to '$TargetFolder'"
      Move-Item $targetFile $TargetFolder -Force -WhatIf
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was hesitant to even comment on this since you're just not taking any of our advise on all the previoous posts, and just repeating what we say in a new question. We are here to help with your code, and not write it for you but, learning isn't a crime so I will just assume you're just unfamiliar with powershell in general.

```
$csvpath = 'C:\tomp\temp.csv'
#$invalid = "[{0}]" -f [RegEx]::Escape(([IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -join ''))
$sourcePath = 'C:\tomp\'

Import-Csv $csvpath -Header Title,FileName,Link -Delimiter ',' | 
  Group-Object Title | 
  ForEach-Object `
    -Begin {

    $FoldersLocation = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\tomp -Directory 
    $Source_Folder   = ($FoldersLocation.Parent.FullName | Select-Object -Unique) 

    #Create array list to hold both columns
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$CombinedRows = @()

    } `
    -Process {

        # Create folder if it doesn't exist
        $Destination = Join-Path -Path $Source_Folder -ChildPath $_.Name
            if ((Test-Path -Path $Destination) -eq $false) { 

                "Created:  $Destination"

                #$null = New-Item -Path ($FoldersLocation.Parent.FullName | Select -Unique) -Name $_.Name -ItemType Directory

            }

        #region Combine two columns
        Foreach ($fileName in $_.Group.FileName) {
       
            $null = $CombinedRows.Add($fileName)

        }
        Foreach ($link in $_.Group.Link) {
       
            $null = $CombinedRows.Add($link)
       
        }
        #endregion      

    } `
    -End {

        Foreach ($name in $FoldersLocation) {

            if ($name.Name -in $CombinedRows) {
                   
                if ($name.Name -match "Showcase"){

                    # No need for output when supplying the -verbose switch
                    "Moving: '$($Name.FullName)' to 'C:\tomp\Lanterna Verde - Le Prime Storie'"
                    
                    # Move-Item -Path $Name.FullName -Destination "C:\tomp\Lanterna Verde - Le Prime Storie" 


                }
                else {

                    # No need for output when supplying the -verbose switch
                     "Moving: '$($Name.FullName)]' to 'C:\tomp\Batman DC'" 

                    # Move-Item -Path $Name.FullName -Destination "C:\tomp\Batman DC" 
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

All it comes down to is control of flow logic. *If* a certain condition is met, then do this, or do something *else* if its not. Added very few inline comments as most of it pretty self explanatory.

I recommend reading up on some powershell instead of hoping others could do everything for you.

- [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/powershell)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you do. I run script but I see [THIS](https://imgur.com/c14bfjo.png). I read your code and comment of your code but after it don't work. It don't create and move folders. No folders are created and no moving of folders is performed. It's correct? because reading your code should be create them

Comment: You did not try to understand the code, if you did, you'd see that the actual cmdlets are commented out. So just remove the `#` out of any cmdlet performing any action.

Comment: Also, that's not the what the code does. It only creates 2 folders. You need to change the Delimeter as well.

Comment: ok, now it moves after change delimiter, but I don't understand why you need to write manually into the script the path `Move-Item -Path $Name.FullName -Destination "C:\tomp\Lanterna Verde - Le Prime Storie` - but if I have 100 folders need I write within for 100 times `"C:\tomp\xxx..` ? it's not useful...

Comment: Second question: why you insert second path (for Batman DC) using another condition `else {..`? and if I have 3 folders? you need to insert every time a condition? it's unclear

Comment: You can change the code as you see fits. If you don't find it useful, don't use it;)

Comment: This script is bad because you need to insert manually the name... for example your "match condition" why do you need use it when I can have 100+ folder names?  `"if ($name.Name -match "Showcase")"` - is not the solution but is a complication. it's as if a plumber came to your house, but instead of welding, he joined the pipes with scotch tape - This is what you did.

Comment: The folder must be moved based on one criterion: only and only if the folders names in `C:\tomp` is on the row of the text file **temp.csv** - yes, but the criterion must not be a particular file name, but if the *folder name* as a variable between an interval of delimiters like `;  ;` any line of the temp.csv text file *already exists*. Then, only if after this match exists, that folder with that particular name can be moved. You wrote the script not as a general condition, but as a particular case. This is the mistake.

Comment: also if I know some other language I don't know every language, sorry